# dplyr alternative for plyr::mapvalues (recode using dictionary)

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr

plyr::mapvalues makes it possible to recode a vector based on a dictionary, i.e., two matched vector of existing and replacement values.

```
library(plyr)
data <- c("a", "b", "c", "a")
dict_old <- c("a", "b", "c")
dict_new <- c("Apple", "Banana", "Carrot")
mapvalues(data, dict_old, dict_new)
[1] "Apple"  "Banana" "Carrot" "Apple"
```

In dplyr, an equivalent result can be obtained by creating a list containing the new values and assigning the old values as names to the list elements:

```
list <- as.list(dict_new)
names(list) <- dict_old
recode(data, !!!list)
[1] "Apple"  "Banana" "Carrot" "Apple"
```

However, that strikes me as rather kludgy. Is there a cleaner way to do this within the tidyverse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way using `stringr` could be:

```
str_replace_all(data, setNames(dict_new, dict_old))

[1] "Apple"  "Banana" "Carrot" "Apple"
```

Comment: Compared to the base R method, `str_replace_all` has the advantage that it doesn't replace values present in `data` but not present in `dict_old` by NAs. Shorter example to compare with the base R version: `str_replace_all(c("x","y","z"),setNames(c("a","b"),c("x","y")))`.

Answer (score 2):

If you think using !!! is 'kludgy', you could always hide it away in a neat function.  This is how I regularly write bespoke mappings:

```
data <- c("a", "b", "c", "a")

my_map <- function (x) {
  dict_old <- c("a", "b", "c")
  dict_new <- c("Apple", "Banana", "Carrot")
  dict <- setNames(dict_new, dict_old)
  dplyr::recode(data, !!!dict)
}

my_map(data)
[1] "Apple"  "Banana" "Carrot" "Apple"
```

Comment: I can't believe they don't just implement mapvalues() in dplyr (eg. as you suggest), as it is a perfect function that so many people use. And actually do not understand what "!!!" does and cannot even find it after a long time searching.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this in `base R`

```
unname(setNames(dict_new, dict_old)[data])
#[1] "Apple"  "Banana" "Carrot" "Apple"
```

Comment: Thank you, I was confused by the fact that `dict_new`, `dict_old` and `data` are all vectors (dict are not dictionaries coming from python and data is not a data frame). A shorter example with all vectors in the same call might help someone else understand `unname(setNames(c("a","b"),c("x","y"))[c("x","y","z")])`.